# XBee PRO S2B communicating with ZigBee HA profile sensors

Tags: zigbee, xbee

Is it possible to communicate with ZigBee HA (Home Automation) profile sensors with XBee PRO S2B and if yes, how? Does anyone know where could I find any specification regarding ZigBee HA profile?

Thank you far any help!

Answer (score 1):

As said above, you can ask for a Zigbee Home Automation Profile [there](http://www.zigbee.org/Standards/ZigBeeHomeAutomation/download.aspx).
That does not include the ZCL, which you'll need to download from the Zigbee Alliance Website too.

It's possible to implement you're own ZHA Appli over S2B (which are programmable modules). Howevere, I tried and I was stuck because the Xbee S2B module does not implement all the ZDP Commands. Might be useful for you to know ! The Digi support confirmed me that you can use the "Match Descriptor Request" for exemple. So you'll need to find other solutions.

Answer (score 0):

The ZigBee Alliance has a limited number of its specifications available for [download](http://zigbee.org/Specifications/ZigBee/download.aspx) to the public.  I don't know whether that includes the ZigBee Cluster Library or not.

It should be possible to join a Home Automation network and use ZDO and ZCL commands to discover endpoints/cluster/attributes on an HA Sensor and then read them.  Digi has released some code for sending ZDO and ZCL requests, but as of now it's only available for their Rabbit-brand embedded systems (as part of [Dynamic C](http://www.digi.com/support/productdetail?pid=4978) 10.70), and the [Programmable XBee](http://www.digi.com/programmablexbeekit) product.

Updated 2016-10-27 to include a link to the ZDO/ZCL code released on GitHub as a portable [XBee ANSI C Host Library](https://github.com/digidotcom/xbee_ansic_library).